# How to map an object inside another object using Automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to do the mapping to display a value that is inside an entity, which is inside another entity that is inside another entity, the sequence is "Hose" > "Equipment" > "Manufacturer" > "RazaoSocial", but not I can make it work correctly.

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
cfg.CreateMap<MangueiraDaOrdemDeServico, MangueiraDaOrdemDeServicoDTO>()
    .ForMember(to => to.FabricanteNome, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Mangueira.Fabricante.RazaoSocial));
```

My complete DTO:

```
using AutoMapper;
using SGE.Extintor.Domain.Administrativo.Entities;
using SGE.Extintor.Domain.Oficina.Entities;
using SGE.Publico.Domain.Entities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SGE.Extintor.Application.Oficina.DTO
{
    public class MangueiraDaOrdemDeServicoDTO
    {
        public MangueiraDaOrdemDeServicoDTO()
        {
            this.Valores = new List<ValorServicoMangueiraDTO>();
        }
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public int? MangueiraId { get; set; }
        public int? OrdemDeServicoDaMangueiraId { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string NumeroMangueira { get; set; }
        public string FabricanteNome { get; set; }
        public string NumeroAbrigo { get; set; }
        public int OrdemDeExibicao { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string StatusClassLabel { get; set; }
        public int TipoDeManutencao { get; set; }
        public string TipoDeManutencaoDisplayName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ValorServicoMangueiraDTO> Valores { get; set; }
        public decimal Total
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Valores?.Sum(x => x.Valor) ?? 0;
            }
        }

        #region Mapping 
        internal static void Mapper(IMapperConfiguration cfg)
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<MangueiraDaOrdemDeServico, MangueiraDaOrdemDeServicoDTO>()
                .ForAllMembers(to => to.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<MangueiraDaOrdemDeServico, MangueiraDaOrdemDeServicoDTO>()
                .ForMember(to => to.Status, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Inspecao.Status.DisplayName))
                .ForMember(to => to.StatusCode, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Inspecao.Status.Code))
                .ForMember(to => to.StatusClassLabel, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Inspecao.Status.ClassLabel))
                .ForMember(to => to.OrdemDeServicoDaMangueiraId, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.OrdemDeServicoDaMangueiraId))
                .ForMember(to => to.OrdemDeExibicao, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.OrdemDeExibicao))
                .ForMember(to => to.MangueiraId, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.MangueiraId))
                .ForMember(to => to.NumeroMangueira, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Mangueira.NumeroMangueira))
                .ForMember(to => to.FabricanteId, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Mangueira.FabricanteId))
                .ForMember(to => to.FabricanteNome, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Mangueira.Fabricante.RazaoSocial))
                .ForMember(to => to.NumeroAbrigo, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Mangueira.NumeroAbrigo))
                .ForMember(to => to.Descricao, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Mangueira.Descricao))
                .ForMember(to => to.Id, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember(to => to.TipoDeManutencaoDisplayName, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Inspecao.TipoDeManutencao.DisplayName))
                .ForMember(to => to.TipoDeManutencao, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Inspecao.TipoDeManutencaoCode))
                .ForMember(to => to.Total, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.Valores, from => from.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<MangueiraDaOrdemDeServicoDTO, MangueiraDaOrdemDeServico>()
                .ForMember(to => to.OrdemDeServicoDaMangueiraId, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.OrdemDeServicoDaMangueiraId))
                .ForMember(to => to.MangueiraId, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.MangueiraId))
                .ForMember(to => to.Inspecao, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.Mangueira, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.ItemPedidoDeManutencao, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.ItemPedidoDeManutencaoId, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.Valores, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.OrdemDeServicoDaMangueira, from => from.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<Mangueira, MangueiraDaOrdemDeServicoDTO>()
                .ForMember(to => to.FabricanteNome, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.Descricao, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Descricao))
                .ForMember(to => to.NumeroAbrigo, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.NumeroAbrigo))
                .ForMember(to => to.NumeroMangueira, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.NumeroMangueira))
                .ForMember(to => to.MangueiraId, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember(to => to.OrdemDeServicoDaMangueiraId, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.OrdemDeExibicao, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.Status, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.StatusClassLabel, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.StatusCode, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.TipoDeManutencaoDisplayName, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.TipoDeManutencao, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.Total, from => from.Ignore())
                .ForMember(to => to.Valores, from => from.Ignore())
                .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.TipoDeManutencao = src.GetTipoManutencao().Code)
                .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.TipoDeManutencaoDisplayName = src.GetTipoManutencao().DisplayName);

            cfg.CreateMap<MangueiraDaOrdemDeServicoDTO, Mangueira>()
                .ForAllMembers(to => to.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<MangueiraDaOrdemDeServicoDTO, Mangueira>()
                .ForMember(to => to.Descricao, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.Descricao))
                .ForMember(to => to.NumeroAbrigo, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.NumeroAbrigo))
                .ForMember(to => to.NumeroMangueira, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.NumeroMangueira))
                .ForMember(to => to.Id, from => from.MapFrom(src => src.MangueiraId));

        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

MangueiraDaOrdemDeServico Entity:

```
using Framework.Domain.Audit.Attribute;
using Framework.Domain.Entities;
using Framework.Domain.Interfaces.Entities;
using SGE.Extintor.Domain.Administrativo.Entities;
using SGE.Extintor.Domain.Common.Enumerations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SGE.Extintor.Domain.Oficina.Entities
{
    //[Auditable(EnumIndexEntityAudit.MangueiraDaOrdemDeServico)]
    public class MangueiraDaOrdemDeServico : BaseEntity<int>
    {
        public MangueiraDaOrdemDeServico()
        {
            this.Valores = new List<ValorServicoMangueira>();
        }

        public int OrdemDeServicoDaMangueiraId { get; set; }
        public int OrdemDeExibicao { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public OrdemDeServicoDaMangueira OrdemDeServicoDaMangueira { get; set; }
        public int MangueiraId { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public Mangueira Mangueira { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public InspecaoDaMangueira Inspecao { get; set; }
        public int? ItemPedidoDeManutencaoId { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public ItemPedidoManutencaoMangueira ItemPedidoDeManutencao { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ValorServicoMangueira> Valores { get; set; }

        public static MangueiraDaOrdemDeServico Gerar(int ordemDeExibicao,ItemPedidoManutencaoMangueira itemPedidoDeManutencao, Mangueira mangueira, OrdemDeServicoDaMangueira ordemDeServicoDaMangueira)
        {
            MangueiraDaOrdemDeServico mangueiraDaOS = new MangueiraDaOrdemDeServico();
            mangueiraDaOS.OrdemDeExibicao = ordemDeExibicao;
            mangueiraDaOS.Mangueira = mangueira;
            mangueiraDaOS.MangueiraId = mangueira.Id;
            mangueiraDaOS.OrdemDeServicoDaMangueira = ordemDeServicoDaMangueira;
            mangueiraDaOS.OrdemDeServicoDaMangueiraId = ordemDeServicoDaMangueira.Id;
            mangueiraDaOS.ItemPedidoDeManutencao = itemPedidoDeManutencao;
            mangueiraDaOS.ItemPedidoDeManutencaoId = itemPedidoDeManutencao.Id;

            return mangueiraDaOS;
        }
    }
}
```

Mangueira Entity:

```
using Framework.Domain.Audit.Attribute;
using Framework.Domain.Common.Enum;
using SGE.Extintor.Domain.Common.Enumerations;
using SGE.Extintor.Domain.Oficina.Entities;
using SGE.Extintor.Domain.Common.Internationalization;
using SGE.Publico.Domain.Common.Enumerations;
using SGE.Publico.Domain.Common.Exceptions;
using SGE.Publico.Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using SGE.Extintor.Domain.Common.Enumerations.Relatorios;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SGE.Extintor.Domain.Administrativo.Entities
{
    [Auditable(EnumIndexEntityAudit.Mangueira)]
    public class Mangueira : Equipamento
    {
        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public override string Descricao
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.Tipo == null) || (!this.TipoId.HasValue) || (this.ComprimentoNominal == 0) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Diametro)) || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Diametro)))
                    return null;

                return $"{this.Tipo.Descricao} {this.Diametro} {this.ComprimentoNominal}";

            }
        }
        public string NumeroMangueira { get; set; }
        public string NumeroAbrigo { get; set; }
        public int? FabricanteUniaoId { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public Fabricante FabricanteUniao { get; set; }
        public string Diametro { get; set; }
        public decimal ComprimentoNominal { get; set; }
        public decimal ComprimentoReal { get; set; }
        public int? TipoId { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public TipoMangueira Tipo { get; set; }
        public decimal PressaoDeEnsaio { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ProximaInspecao { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UltimaInspecao { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ProximaManutencao { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UltimaManutencao { get; set; }

        public string SituacaoId { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public SituacaoEquipamento Situacao { get; set; }
        public int? NumeroUltimaOS { get; set; }
        public int? UltimaOSId { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public OrdemDeServicoDaMangueira UltimaOS { get; set; }
        public string FinalidadeDoEquipamentoCode
        {
            get
            {
                return FinalidadeDoEquipamento?.Code;
            }

            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    FinalidadeDoEquipamento = Enumeration.From<EnumFinalidadeDoEquipamento>(item => value == item.Code);
                else
                    FinalidadeDoEquipamento = null;
            }
        }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public EnumFinalidadeDoEquipamento FinalidadeDoEquipamento { get; set; }

        /*public string Localizacao { get; set; }*/
        public string TempoDeInspecaoEManutencaoPadraoCode
        {
            get
            {
                return TempoDeInspecaoEManutencaoPadrao?.Code;
            }

            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    TempoDeInspecaoEManutencaoPadrao = Enumeration.From<EnumSimOuNao>(item => value == item.Code);
                else
                    TempoDeInspecaoEManutencaoPadrao = null;
            }
        }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public EnumSimOuNao TempoDeInspecaoEManutencaoPadrao { get; set; }
        public int? TempoDeInspecaoExclusivo { get; set; }
        public int? TempoDeManutencaoExclusivo { get; set; }
        public int? ParceiroCorporativoId { get; set; }
        public int? MangueiraCorporativoId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UltimaInspecaoVisual { get; set; }


        #region Metodos
        public EnumTipoDeManutencaoInspecaoDaMangueira GetTipoManutencao(int? mes = null, int? ano = null)
        {
            EnumTipoDeManutencaoInspecaoDaMangueira tipo = null;

            if (!this.ProximaInspecao.HasValue || !this.ProximaManutencao.HasValue)
                return EnumTipoDeManutencaoInspecaoDaMangueira.Manutencao;

            DateTime? proximaInspecao = new DateTime(this.ProximaInspecao.Value.Year, this.ProximaInspecao.Value.Month, 1);
            DateTime? proximaManutencao = new DateTime(this.ProximaManutencao.Value.Year, this.ProximaManutencao.Value.Month, 1);
            DateTime data;

            if (mes.HasValue || ano.HasValue)
                data = new DateTime(ano.Value, mes.Value, 1);
            else
                data = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

            int intervalorMan = (int)this.DiasVencimentoProximaManutencao;          

            if (intervalorMan <= 30)            
                tipo = EnumTipoDeManutencaoInspecaoDaMangueira.Manutencao;            
            else
                tipo = EnumTipoDeManutencaoInspecaoDaMangueira.Inspecao;

            //if (data >= proximaManutencao)
            //    tipo = EnumTipoDeManutencaoInspecaoDaMangueira.Manutencao;
            //else
            //    tipo = EnumTipoDeManutencaoInspecaoDaMangueira.Inspecao;

            return tipo;
        }


        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public int? DiasVencimentoProximaInspecao
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ProximaInspecao.HasValue)
                {
                    TimeSpan result = this.ProximaInspecao.Value - DateTime.Now.Date;
                    return result.Days;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public int? DiasVencimentoProximaManutencao
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ProximaManutencao.HasValue)
                {
                    TimeSpan result = this.ProximaManutencao.Value - DateTime.Now.Date;
                    return result.Days;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }
        }
        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public EnumOrdemVencimento Status
        {
            get
            {
                int dias = -1;
                if (this.DiasVencimentoProximaInspecao.HasValue && this.DiasVencimentoProximaManutencao.HasValue)
                {

                    if (this.DiasVencimentoProximaInspecao <= this.DiasVencimentoProximaManutencao)
                    {
                        dias = this.DiasVencimentoProximaInspecao.Value;
                    }
                    else if (this.DiasVencimentoProximaManutencao <= this.DiasVencimentoProximaInspecao)
                    {
                        dias = this.DiasVencimentoProximaManutencao.Value;
                    }

                    if (dias > EnumOrdemVencimento.AVencer.Dias)
                        return EnumOrdemVencimento.AVencer;
                    else if (dias >= EnumOrdemVencimento.Vencidas.Dias && dias <= EnumOrdemVencimento.AVencer30Dias.Dias)
                        return EnumOrdemVencimento.AVencer30Dias;
                    else
                        return EnumOrdemVencimento.Vencidas;
                }
                else
                {
                    return EnumOrdemVencimento.DataNaoInformada;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Atualizar(ItemPedidoManutencaoMangueira item, int clienteId, int responsavelId, int unidadeOrganizacionalId)
        {
            ClienteId = clienteId;
            ResponsavelId = responsavelId;
            MangueiraCorporativoId = item.MngCorpId;
            ParceiroCorporativoId = item.PedidoManutencao.ParceiroCorporativoId;
            UnidadeOrganizacionalDoClienteId = unidadeOrganizacionalId;
            NumeroMangueira = item.MngCorpNumero;
            NumeroAbrigo = item.MngCorpNumeroAbrigo;
            FabricanteId = item.MngCorpFabricante.Value;
            FabricanteUniaoId = item.MngCorpFabricanteUniaoId;
            Diametro = item.MngCorpDiametro;
            ComprimentoNominal = item.MngCorpComprimentoNominal;
            ComprimentoReal = item.MngCorpComprimentoReal;
            TipoId = item.MngCorpTipoId;
            Fabricacao = item.MngCorpFabricacao;
            PressaoDeEnsaio = item.MngCorpPressaoEnsaio;
            ProximaInspecao = item.MngCorpProximaInspecao;
            ProximaManutencao = item.MngCorpProximaManutencao;
            UltimaInspecao = item.MngCorpUltimaInspecao;
            UltimaManutencao = item.MngCorpUltimaManutencao;
            Localizacao = item.MngCorpLocalizacaoNome;
            SituacaoId = item.MngCorpSituacao;
            TempoDeInspecaoEManutencaoPadrao = EnumSimOuNao.Sim;
        }

        public static Mangueira Gerar(ItemPedidoManutencaoMangueira item, int clienteId, int responsavelId, int unidadeOrganizacionalId)
        {
            Mangueira mangueira = new Mangueira();
            mangueira.ClienteId = clienteId;
            mangueira.ResponsavelId = responsavelId;
            mangueira.MangueiraCorporativoId = item.MngCorpId;
            mangueira.ParceiroCorporativoId = item.PedidoManutencao.ParceiroCorporativoId;
            mangueira.UnidadeOrganizacionalDoClienteId = unidadeOrganizacionalId;
            mangueira.NumeroMangueira = item.MngCorpNumero;
            mangueira.NumeroAbrigo = item.MngCorpNumeroAbrigo;
            mangueira.FabricanteId = item.MngCorpFabricante.Value;
            mangueira.FabricanteUniaoId = item.MngCorpFabricanteUniaoId;
            mangueira.Diametro = item.MngCorpDiametro;
            mangueira.ComprimentoNominal = item.MngCorpComprimentoNominal;
            mangueira.ComprimentoReal = item.MngCorpComprimentoReal;
            mangueira.TipoId = item.MngCorpTipoId;
            mangueira.Fabricacao = item.MngCorpFabricacao;
            mangueira.PressaoDeEnsaio = item.MngCorpPressaoEnsaio;
            mangueira.ProximaInspecao = item.MngCorpProximaInspecao;
            mangueira.ProximaManutencao = item.MngCorpProximaManutencao;
            mangueira.UltimaInspecao = item.MngCorpUltimaInspecao;
            mangueira.UltimaManutencao = item.MngCorpUltimaManutencao;
            mangueira.Localizacao = item.MngCorpLocalizacaoNome;
            mangueira.SituacaoId = item.MngCorpSituacao;
            mangueira.TempoDeInspecaoEManutencaoPadrao = EnumSimOuNao.Sim;

            return mangueira;
        }       
    }
}
```

Equipamento Entity:

```
using Framework.Domain.Audit.Attribute;
using Framework.Domain.Entities;
using Framework.Domain.Interfaces.Entities;
using SGE.Extintor.Domain.Common.DTO;
using SGE.Extintor.Domain.Common.Enumerations;
using SGE.Global.Domain.Administrativo.Entities;
using SGE.Publico.Domain.Common.Exceptions;
using SGE.Publico.Domain.Entities;
using System;

namespace SGE.Extintor.Domain.Administrativo.Entities
{
    [Auditable(EnumIndexEntityAudit.Equipamento)]
    public abstract class Equipamento : BaseEntity<int>
    {
        public abstract string Descricao { get;}
      
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }
        public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

        public int ResponsavelId { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public RecursoHumanoDoCliente Responsavel { get; set; }

        public int UnidadeOrganizacionalDoClienteId { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public UnidadeOrganizacionalDoCliente UnidadeOrganizacionalDoCliente { get; set; }

        public string Localizacao { get; set; }
        public int FabricanteId { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public Fabricante Fabricante { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Fabricacao { get; set; }
        public DateTime Cadastro { get; set; }

        [IgnoreAuditable]
        public EquipamentoDTO DTO { get { return new EquipamentoDTO { Id = Id, Descricao = Descricao }; } }

        #region Metodos
        public void SetId(int id) => Id = id;

        private bool validarCliente()
        {
            return this.ClienteId > 0;
        }
        private bool validarUnidadeId()
        {
            return this.UnidadeOrganizacionalDoClienteId > 0;
        }
        private bool validarResponsavelId()
        {
            return this.ResponsavelId > 0;
        }
        private bool validarFabricanteId()
        {
            return this.FabricanteId > 0;
        }
        public void ValidarInsertUpdate()
        {
            if (!validarCliente())
                throw new RequiredFieldException(nameof(this.ClienteId));

            if (!validarUnidadeId())
                throw new RequiredFieldException(nameof(this.UnidadeOrganizacionalDoClienteId));

            if (!validarResponsavelId())
                throw new RequiredFieldException(nameof(this.ResponsavelId));

            if (!validarFabricanteId())
                throw new RequiredFieldException(nameof(this.FabricanteId));
        }
        #endregion Metodos
    }
}
```

Fabricante Entity:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Framework.Domain.Common.Enum;
using Framework.Domain.Entities;
using SGE.Publico.Domain.Common.Enumerations;
using SGE.Publico.Domain.Common.Exceptions;
using SGE.Publico.Domain.Common.Internationalization;
using SGE.Publico.Domain.Common.ValidatorExtensions;

namespace SGE.Publico.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Fabricante : BaseEntity<int>
    {
        public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

        public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

        public string SiglaImpressao { get; set; }

        public string Telefone { get; set; }

        public string CNPJ { get; set; }

        public string Endereco { get; set; }

        public string NumeroEndereco { get; set; }

        public string Complemento { get; set; }

        public string Bairro { get; set; }

        public string CEP { get; set; }

        public int? CidadeId { get; set; }

        public Cidade Cidade { get; set; }

        public string NomeContato { get; set; }

        public string EmailContato { get; set; }

        public string AbrigoCode { get; set; }

        public string HidranteCode { get; set; }

        public string BotoeiraCode { get; set; }

        public string ExtintorCode { get; set; }

        public string KitEmergenciaCode { get; set; }

        public string MangueiraCode { get; set; }

        public string OffRoadCode { get; set; }

        public string UniaoCode { get; set; }

        public string CilindroArCode { get; set; }

        public string LuminariaEmergenciaCode { get; set; }

        public string CasaBombaCode { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ConsumoLGE> ConsumosLGE { get; set; }

        public EnumSimOuNao Abrigo
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumeration.From((EnumSimOuNao item) => AbrigoCode == item.Code);
            }
            set
            {
                AbrigoCode = value?.Code;
            }
        }

        public EnumSimOuNao Botoeira
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumeration.From((EnumSimOuNao item) => BotoeiraCode == item.Code);
            }
            set
            {
                BotoeiraCode = value?.Code;
            }
        }

        public EnumSimOuNao Hidrante
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumeration.From((EnumSimOuNao item) => HidranteCode == item.Code);
            }
            set
            {
                HidranteCode = value?.Code;
            }
        }

        public EnumSimOuNao Extintor
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumeration.From((EnumSimOuNao item) => ExtintorCode == item.Code);
            }
            set
            {
                ExtintorCode = value?.Code;
            }
        }

        public EnumSimOuNao KitEmergencia
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumeration.From((EnumSimOuNao item) => KitEmergenciaCode == item.Code);
            }
            set
            {
                KitEmergenciaCode = value?.Code;
            }
        }

        public EnumSimOuNao Mangueira
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumeration.From((EnumSimOuNao item) => MangueiraCode == item.Code);
            }
            set
            {
                MangueiraCode = value?.Code;
            }
        }

        public EnumSimOuNao OffRoad
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumeration.From((EnumSimOuNao item) => OffRoadCode == item.Code);
            }
            set
            {
                OffRoadCode = value?.Code;
            }
        }

        public EnumSimOuNao Uniao
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumeration.From((EnumSimOuNao item) => UniaoCode == item.Code);
            }
            set
            {
                UniaoCode = value?.Code;
            }
        }

        public EnumSimOuNao CilindroAr
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumeration.From((EnumSimOuNao item) => CilindroArCode == item.Code);
            }
            set
            {
                CilindroArCode = value?.Code;
            }
        }

        public EnumSimOuNao LuminariaEmergencia
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumeration.From((EnumSimOuNao item) => LuminariaEmergenciaCode == item.Code);
            }
            set
            {
                LuminariaEmergenciaCode = value?.Code;
            }
        }

        public EnumSimOuNao CasaBomba
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumeration.From((EnumSimOuNao item) => CasaBombaCode == item.Code);
            }
            set
            {
                CasaBombaCode = value?.Code;
            }
        }

        public Fabricante()
        {
        }

        public Fabricante(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        private bool validarId()
        {
            return Id > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I just don't know how to make it work.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, you don't filled the object "Inspecao" in "Gerar" method, but you tried to use it in mapping. May be the error occurred here.